# Azure HTTPS Endpoint Local Debug Crash w/ "Error Attaching the Debugger"

Tags: azure, https, azure-web-roles

I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise, Azure SDK 2.0, Azure Web Role Project in VS2012.

As soon as I add an https endpoint in the endpoints section of my Azure Cloud Project properties, I immediately get the following error:

> There was an error attaching the debugger to the role instance. Unable to attach. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

As soon as i remove the https endpoint, or change the enpoint type to http, everything works. I have also tried running https on ports greater than 1000+, still no good.

It deploys to live fine, and the certificates are obviously then all good.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

My IISConfigurator.log looks like so:

```
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00000908:00000005, 2013/08/02 23:16:52.448, INFO ] Adding binding 127.255.0.0:82: to site deployment20(284).Widget.AzureProjV2.Widget.Web_IN_0_Web
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00000908:00000005, 2013/08/02 23:16:52.448, INFO ] Adding binding 127.255.0.0:446: to site deployment20(284).Widget.AzureProjV2.Widget.Web_IN_0_Web
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00000908:00000005, 2013/08/02 23:16:53.211, ERROR] Caught exception
IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00000908:00000005, 2013/08/02 23:16:53.213, ERROR] Exception:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800401F3): Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostProperty.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetPropertyValue(IAppHostProperty property)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding.get_CertificateHash()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection.Add(Binding binding)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.WasManager.DeploySite(String roleId, WASite roleSite, String appPoolName, String sitePath, String iisLogsRootFolder, String failedRequestLogsRootFolder, List`1 bindings, List`1 protocols, FileManager fileManager, WAAppPool defaultAppPoolSettings, String roleGuid, String& appPoolSid, List`1 appPoolsAdded, String configPath)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.WasContainer.DeploySite(String roleId, WASite roleSite, String appPoolName, String sitePath, String iisLogsRootFolder, String failedRequestLogsRootFolder, List`1 bindings, List`1 protocols, FileManager fileManager, WAAppPool defaultAppPoolSettings, String roleGuid, String& appPoolSid, List`1 appPoolsAdded, String configPath)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.IISConfigurator.IISConfigurator.Deploy(String roleId, WebAppModel webAppModel, String roleRootDirectory, String sitesDestinationRootDirectory, String diagnosticsRootDirectory, String roleGuid, String configPath)


IISConfigurator Information: 0 : [00000908:00000007, 2013/08/02 23:16:57.399, INFO ] Clean operation called over WCF interface with prefix 'deployment20(284)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what will now make the 4th time i've fixed an azure "attaching the debugger" error (for all different reasons) with this process, here is how you fix this.

Actually, my experience is proving this is how you fix EVERY "attaching the debugger" error.

1. Download the latest ver of Azure SDK if you're not latest
2. Remove your azure proj from your solution
3. Make an entirely new cloud/azure proj in solution
4. Copy the settings from your old proj into the new one (but not by copy/pasting the whole cscfg/csdef files-- theres azure-version-specific stuff in there. Only copy specific lines you need.)